# Making sure an object will implements an interface

Tags: java, interface, proxy-classes

I got a class which uses a `Proxy`. It looks something like this:

```
public class BarWrapper
{
    private final Bar bar;

    public BarWrapper(Bar bar)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public int someMethodInBar()
    {
        return bar.someMethodInBar();
    }

    public int someMethodInBar2()
    {
        return bar.someMethodInBar2();
    }

    public int someMethodInBar3()
    {
        return bar.someMethodInBar3();
    }


    // etc
}
```

The `Bar` is some super class and the dynamic type will be a derivative.

I got an interface and I want the wrapper to implement that interface and keep using the proxy with the same methods, but `Bar` itself doesn't implement that interface and I don't have any access to it. How can I force the user to pass a dynamic type that is not only a derivative of `Bar` but also implements the interface so I will have no problem doing this:

```
(Iinterface)bar.interfaceMethod();
```

Comment: `if (!bar instanceof Iinterface) throw new IllegalArgumentException()`?

Comment: I prefer to find a way to force it on compilation time

Comment: How about changing the constructor to `public BarWrapper(Iinterface bar) [...]`. If you do use any of the methods that are in `Bar` but not in `Iinterface`, i suggest you add these to `Iinterface` (perhapts extend the interface into a `IinterfaceBar`).

Comment: one way that I can see is to use reflection to see if the object implements the interface and throw an exception if it doesn't.  Edit - beat to it.

Comment: @RonThompson Please read the first two comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the wrapped object to be both a subclass of Bar and an instance of the interface Foo, that Bar doesn't implement, then the only way I see is to accept a subclass of Bar that implements Foo:

```
public abstract FooBar extends Bar implements Foo {
}
```

That will do what you want: the user will be forced to extend FooBar, and thus to provide a subclass of Bar that implements Foo.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking the object `Bar`, only accept the interface.

```
private final Iinterface bar;
public BarWrapper(Iinterface bar)
{
    this.bar = bar;
}
```

That does require your proxy to only call methods in the interface. It is possible you also want to call methods that are in `Bar`, but not `Iinterface`. The only way to enforce that at compile time, is to add these methods to the interface, perhaps extend the interface:

```
public interface IinterfaceBarWrapper implements Iinterface
{
    public void someMethodInBar();
    public void someMethodInBar2();
    public void someMethodInBar3();
}
```

...

```
private final IinterfaceBarWrapper bar;
public BarWrapper(IinterfaceBarWrapper bar)
{
    this.bar = bar;
}
```

Comment: That won't force the use to extend Bar though. You can implement IinterfaceBarWrapper without extending Bar at all. But I agree that this is the cleanest OO way. The wrapper shouldn't care whether the interface methods are implemented by extending Bar or not.

Comment: @JBNizet You already covered that with your answer, I didn't feel like duplicating what was already stated. I can think of three solutions here: Throw a exception at runtime, add a abstract class that extend bar and the interface, or extend the interface (if you use non-interface methods at least, else just use the interface directly). They all have there own merits and demerits.